# How can match only the rows that doesn't start with

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match code lines, 
my issue is to ignore comments (lines those start with slash-/)

For example:

```
/(\w+)(?:\s|\t)(?:\=)(?:\s|\t)+/g
```

On this string:

test1 = "b"
  test2 = "d"
  //test3 = "dsf"

Should return:

```
test1
test2
```

My current pattern, of course returns:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I'm aware of `(?<!`, but because I'm using javascript it doesn't work for me. about `(?!` I believe it's not for the same usage (fix me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to look at the input line-by-line and look for the lines which don't match the comments? Few regex engines support "inverse matches". Of the top of my head, neither Python's nor C#s do.

Comment: Code lines are not a regular language. Regular expressions are a poor choice with which to parse them. Consider building an actual parser instead - it might be more intimidating, but it will certainly be less stressful than figuring out all the edge cases, such as `test1 = "will it break? // Maybe."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `^` as the start-of-line anchor (with `m` modifier), and by requiring `\w` at the start of the line, the line will not match. You could still allow for some white space at the start of the line:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*\=
```

NB: `\t` is already matched by `\s`, so there is no need to do `\s|\t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
output=input.split("\n").map(line=>line.split("//")[0]);
```

Will return:

```
['test1="b"','test2="d"']
```

Then you can go further...